# "Drive" in compounds

Tags: compounds

*Sex drive* means you want sex. Does *blood drive* mean you want to kill people? Does *talk drive* mean you (want to) talk a lot?  I know it might not be something people say a lot if at all, but does it make sense?

Comment: A Blood Drive is where people donate a pint of blood to help other people.

Comment: *Sex drive* doesn't mean you **want** sex. It describes the general or average level of libido. There aren't many other compounds of *drive* — if any — which have that sense.

Comment: "Drive" in these words doesn't mean that you *want* something, but rather a measure of your willingness to put in effort to get that thing.  As @AndrewLeach points out, *sex drive* doesn't mean you want sex, it is a measure of the level of effort you put into finding sex.

Comment: Is there a word I can use to expression the intended idea? Oh! Lust! **Blood lust? talk lust?**

Comment: This question can be answered simply by consulting a good dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

All of your examples are somewhat unique. They are terms that you will pick up with observation and practice.

To give some insight on your examples, I think you might be looking for:

"bloodthirsty" rather than blood drive;

"talkative" or "chatty" rather than talk drive.

Also common is constructing this the other way, as someone might have a "drive to *_*_." Here, "drive" is similar to "desire" or "intent," with a somewhat stronger connotation. Examples:

"He had drive to improve his piano playing."
"They had drive to be successful."